# Why is the "When one or more files are added or modified (metadata only)" File System trigger on Logic Apps triggering instances with empty body?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic Apps workflow, which is triggered by the `When one or more files are added or modified (metadata only)` File System connector trigger. It's supposed to run every 5 minutes, and allow a maximum of 10 files per instance.

[image]

This is the code behind the trigger

```
"When_one_or_more_files_are_added_or_modified_(metadata_only)": {
"inputs": {
    "host": {
        "connection": {
            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['filesystem']['connectionId']"
        }
    },
    "method": "get",
    "path": "/datasets/default/triggers/batch/onupdatedfile",
    "queries": {
        "folderId": "XFx5b3VhcmVzbWFydFxidXRcdGhpc1xpc1xzZWNyZXQ=",
        "maxFileCount": 10
    }
},
"metadata": {
    "XFx5b3VhcmVzbWFydFxidXRcdGhpc1xpc1xzZWNyZXQ=": "\\hidden\"
},
"recurrence": {
    "frequency": "Minute",
    "interval": 5
},
"type": "ApiConnection"
```

}

I've removed the `splitOn` property from the trigger, so I can get a list of files. However, every 5 minutes, when there are files (less than 10), more than one instance is triggered, and based on many tests, there is always one with empty body. As shown below:

[image]

Some of my tests:

- 1 file in the folder, Two instances are fired. One instance with one
  file, and one instance with no files.
- 2 files in the folder, 3 instances are fired. 1, 0, and 1 files
  correspondingly.
- 3 files in the folder, 3 instances are fired. 2, 0, and 1 files
  correspondingly.
- 5 files in the folder, 3 instances are fired. 4, 0, and 1 files
  correspondingly.
- 10 files in the folder, 3 instances are fired. 9, 0, and 1 files
  correspondingly.

Is there something I need to configure differently so I get only 1 instance with all the files (when less than 10) and no instance with an empty body?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the issue? I'm seeing similar weird behaviour with this trigger.

Comment: Hi @Rowan, please see the answer that I just added below.

Answer (score 2):

The product team has mentioned that this is the behaviour of the current implementation of the connector. To avoid this, the best approach is not to remove the `splitOn` from the trigger and let it instantiate one instance per file.

Comment: Its 2021 and the issue still exists.